# Asterisk in the argument name with C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I want to implement cross-platform build of my DLL with mingw32/VC.
At the moment everything is perfect with mingw side. However I have to wrap several things in macro for VC (it is built as /TC), for example:

```
void __attribute__((fastcall)) do1 (  A*, B , C, D );
bool __attribute__((fastcall)) ( *do2 ) ( E*, F );
```

The first one is simple, just a macro:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__
    #define __FASTCALL__ __attribute__((fastcall))
#elif _MSC_VER
    #define __FASTCALL__ __fastcall
#else
    #error "unsupported compiler"
#endif
```

The problem comes with the second one. Calling convention with a function pointer should looks like

```
bool ( __fastcall *do2 ) ( E*, F );
```

I tried the following macro (I skipped ifdef part):

```
#define __FASTCALLP__(func) (__attribute__((fastcall))(*##func))
#define __FASTCALLP__(func) (__fastcall *##func)
```

or if pass function name with asterisk:

```
#define __FASTCALLP__(func) (__attribute__((fastcall))(##func))
#define __FASTCALLP__(func) (__fastcall ##func)
```

Both failed with

> error: pasting "*" and "function_name" does not give a valid
>   preprocessing token

May I wrong at my approach at all? Or I have to ifdef the whole code blocks or separate it to different files?

Comment: Does this work: Simply omit the `##` before `func`?

Comment: Well.... So stupid for me not to check such a simple way :) Do it as answer please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the Concatenation-Operator `##`. It will produce a new preprocessor token by concatenating the left- and right-hand-side, which does not exists (`*do2` is no defined token)

Simply omit it and write like this (omitting `#ifdef`s):

```
#define __FASTCALL__(func) (__attribute__((fastcall))(func))
#define __FASTCALL__(func) (__fastcall func)
```

and use like this:

```
bool __FASTCALL__(do1)(A*, B , C, D);
bool __FASTCALL__(*do2)(E*, F);
```